# subtitle alignment in UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel

i`m trying to build a table view with subtitle text in cells

the problem is when i try to set the alignment of the subtitle text to the right it doesn't work, but it works fine with the main text

here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;
}
```

when i remove the subtitle code the alignment works fine

any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so subclass UITableView Cell and customize the labels with init. You can override layoutSubviews and move the labels to the right:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 68.0, 80.0, self.frame.size.height);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 68.0, 120.0, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

These are just example values so you can get the idea.

Comment: @H.aLFaRSi let me know, if i can help in anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are initializing cell twice:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

You can create custom cell with two labels and provide alignment to those label.Follow these steps:

1.Add new file subclass of UITableViewCell say labelCustomCell.
2.In labelCustomCell create two labels say label1 and label2.
3.In initWithStyle method allocate these labels and provide alignment.
4.In layoutSubViews method assign frame to those labels.
5.In cellForRowAtIndexPath method write following code:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DataEntryCell";
                labelCustomCell *cell = (labelCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[labelCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                }
cell.label1.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.label2.text = @"test";
```

Do not forget to import labelCustomCell.